# How to stop the single processor in nifi1.1.0 using rest api

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to stop the processor which is in running state using the PUT method in rest api `/processors/{id}`.

I am able to start the processor by changing the state in the component as follows `"state": "RUNNING"`, and runStatus in the aggregatesnapshot as `"runStatus": "Running"`.

Similarly I tried to stop the processor by changing the state as STOPPED but facing an error as

> 9204b68d-0159-1000-7d8f-720592b2a2dd is not stopped (409 error conflict nd 400 Badrequest).

Please let me know how to stop the processor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

you can able to stop processor using rest api.

**Example:**

i having GetFile(ID:9204b68d-0159-1000-7d8f-720592b2a2dd) processor in UI.

**RestAPI Url:**

```
http://<host>:<port>/nifi-api/processors/9204b68d-0159-1000-7d8f-720592b2a2dd
```

Here json content i have passed as PUT Request to stop processor.

```
{
  "status": {
    "runStatus": "STOPPED"
  },
  "component": {
    "state": "STOPPED",
    "id": "9204b68d-0159-1000-7d8f-720592b2a2dd"
  },
  "id": "9204b68d-0159-1000-7d8f-720592b2a2dd",
  "revision": {
    "version": 10,
    "clientId": "ab010dd6-0159-1000-615b-f095502a7ceb"
  }
}
```

Revision and Status are most important things in stop the processor from RestAPI.

It works well for me.Try it.

And let me know if not worked.

Comment: hi, this helped me. may I know if there is a way to also TERMINATE the processor via rest? like in UI, sometimes when you stop, it still has the tasks running so we do TERMINATE instead.