# Stopping invokeHttp processor by rest api

Tags: javascript, rest, apache-nifi

I want to stop  my invokehttp processor as soon as it's response fails ,is it possible to make it by another  inovokehttp processor? I  have read this solution: 
[How to stop the single processor in nifi1.1.0 using rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713086/how-to-stop-the-single-processor-in-nifi1-1-0-using-rest-api).
 I  have already tried to use put request in my another invokehttp processor(which is connected to previous one with failure connection ) by this  link http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/processors/ea5db028-015d-1000-5ad5-80fd006dda92 but it doesn't  work([image])  will i need  to generate flowfile with realated code:

```
{
  "status": {
    "runStatus": "STOPPED"
  },
  "component": {
    "state": "STOPPED",
    "id": "9204b68d-0159-1000-7d8f-720592b2a2dd"
  },
  "id": "9204b68d-0159-1000-7d8f-720592b2a2dd",
  "revision": {
    "version": 10,
    "clientId": "ab010dd6-0159-1000-615b-f095502a7ceb"
  }
}
```

or there is another way( actually i haven't understand  how to use this code in flowfile)

Comment: is it possible  to use rest api if my service isn't rest? and i also want to  kow what is this clientID  and  how can i find it

Comment: open dev tools in your browser (`F12`), select the `Network` tab, stop the target `invokeHttp` processor, and check the parameters of the request that stopped your processor. then just repeat the same request and parameters in your nifi processor.

Comment: FYI: nifi-api documentation https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/

Comment: I have all needed  parameter now  included clentId( thank you  for it) do  you  know  how can i link  json content  posted below to my put request in invokehttp request should i invoke this 'service'(for stoping processor) internally in  flowfile  or  is there any  way i can send  request  body in invokehttp processor?

Comment: read the manual. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html

`FlowFile attributes are converted to HTTP headers and the FlowFile contents are included as the body of the request (if the HTTP Method is PUT, POST or PATCH)` Means you have to put your POST request content into flow file before `invokeHttp`

Comment: Ok  , thank  you ....