# Is there a way to start and stop apache nifi process group using command line?

Tags: apache-nifi

Trying to start the process group I created in apache nifi using the command line

I already installed curl and run the command below:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"id":"12ef79d6-016e-1000-c7bd-b71e01f3e1b6","state":"RUNNING"}' http://localhost:8085/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/12ef79d6-016e-1000-c7bd-b71e01f3e1b6;
```

where in the process groupid is: 12ef79d6-016e-1000-c7bd-b71e01f3e1b6

I'm new with apache nifi and don't know if I am doing it right or wrong

Comment: Similar  question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41713086

Comment: press F12 in browser (dev tools), switch to network tab, perform required operation from browser, right-click on corresponding network call and select `copy as CURL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop the single processor in nifi1.1.0 using rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713086/how-to-stop-the-single-processor-in-nifi1-1-0-using-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the status of the group or individual processors after issuing the stop command.
If a single processor inside your group fails to stop, you will need to list the process members of the group, perform a status check on each of them, then send a terminate command to that specific processor to force it to stop.Followed by another status check until all members are stopped.